# How to create a MongoDB Array and use it on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, discord.js

I am creating a Discord Bot, this is a problem I faced when I try to create an Array of data for MongoDB.

I don't have a bigger knowledge of MongoDB. So actually I don't know how to work with MongoDB arrays.

CountersSchema.js

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');

const countersSchema = new Schema({
    Guild: { type: String, required: true },
    Counters: [
        {
            Names: { type: String, required: true },
            Types: { type: String, required: true },
            Channels: { type: String, required: true }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = model(`counters`, countersSchema);
```

I tried to create an array in here. I'm not sure whether this is correct or wrong.

The thing I want to do is, let users create counters for their Discord servers. And I want them to only allow max 5 counters per server. So I created this schema to store that data for each counter they create.

I want this `Guild` value to be unique. which is the id of the server. And I want `Names` , `Types` & `Channels` to be an arrays of up to 5 values and falls under the `Guild` value.

Counters.js

```
const counterChannels = require('../../Schemas/CountersSchema');

const data = async (interaction) => {
    try {
        return await counterChannels.findOne({ Guild: interaction.guild.id });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while fetching counters:', error);
        return null;
    }
};

const existingCounter = await data(interaction);

if (existingCounter) {
    // Check if the maximum number of counters is reached
    if (existingCounter.Counters.length >= 5) {
       return;
    };

    await counterChannels.updateOne(
    { Guild: guild.id },
    {
        $push: {
        Counters: {
            Names: givenName, // givenName Declaration not included.
            Types: counterType, // counterType Declaration not included.
            Channels: createdCounter.id // createdCounter Declaration not included.
        }
        }
    }
    );

} else {
    await counterChannels.create({
    Guild: guild.id,
    Counters: [{
        Names: givenName,
        Types: counterType,
        Channels: createdCounter.id
    }]
    });
}
```

This is only a part of the Counters.js file. This is how I tried to find if there are any previous data is available in the db.
And if no data available, I want to create a new entry under the guild id and assign these 3 values to that array.
If previous data available, **I only want to** assign new values to the array and keep the `Guild` as it is.

**So, I want your help in here to correctly do this. I don't think I have done this correctly.**

There is one more thing. That is how to call the data using the array.

ServerCounters.js

```
const serverCounters = require('../Schemas/CountersSchema');

async execute (member) {
   const data = await serverCounters.find({Guild: member.guild.id});
   if(!data.length) return;

   const counterType = data.map(doc => doc.Types);
   const counterChannel = data.map(doc => doc.Channels);
   const counterName = data.map(doc => doc.Names);
}
```

in this code, I want to check is there counter data available for the server. just like the previous Counters.js file. After that, I want to devide the data according to the values of `Types`. So let's say if one of the values in `Types` array is `'Total Members'`, then I want to get the values of the other two arrays that are included along with the `'Total Members'` for `Types`.

So, this is what I'm looking for the help with.

- Create 3 arrays with up to 5 different values. Named `Types` , `Names` , and `Channels` under the `Guild`.
- Check if there are already 5 values for that 3 arrays under the interacting guild's id. (in Counters.js)
- If no data available, create new entry for that guild.
- If less than 5 values available, insert current data to that 3 arrays also.
- Find corresponding values of the `Names` and `Channels` arrays using values of `Types` array.

Comment: Something is not clear for me. In the model you created, the field `Counters` is an array of  `Counter` where `Counter` has 3 fields `Types`, `Names` and `Channels`. 
Then you say "Check if there are already 5 values for that 3 arrays under the interacting guild's id.", but there is not 3 arrays, only `Counters` is an array. The other fields are string.

Comment: I don't know much about mongoDB. it is my current file. I asked to correct what l've did wrong in these 3 files. As for the Schema file, I want 3 arrays Named Names, Types and Channels. Not a single array named Counters.

Comment: Currently, your code provide a single array named Counters, where each element is an object with the 3 fields Name Type and Channel. It is the right way if the name, type and channel are related to each other. And since you want to find the `corresponding values of Name and Channel using value of Type` that might be the way.

Comment: So how about this part: `if (existingCounter.Counters.length >= 5` will this check is there 5 or more values available for each object?

Comment: Yes, but it could generate an error if there is no `Counters` in the document. You should maybe check the `null` possibility with `if ((existingCounter?.Counters ?? []).length >=5)`. But i don't know why you would use return here.

Answer (score 0):

According to our exchages in comments, your schema seems correct for the issue you mentionned. But you should consider adding a `unique : true` on the Guild field since you said it must be unique.

```
    Guild: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
```

The data will be stored in collection named `counters`.

Each document of your collection will look as follow :

```
{
  "Guild" : "myFirstGuild",
  "Counters" : [
    {
      "Names" : "toto",
      "Types" : "ABC",
      "Channels" : "myStringValue",
    },
    {
      "Names" : "foo",
      "Types" : "XYZ",
      "Channels" : "anotherStringValue",
    },
    {
      "Names" : "bar",
      "Types" : "IDK",
      "Channels" : "anotherOne",
    },
  ]
}
```

It's will allow you to retrieve easily the matching value between a `Types` and it's `Names` value or `Channels` value.

I simplify the update or insert method by using the `upsert` option. If no document matches the query option, it will create one.

```
if (existingCounter && (existingCounter?.Counter ?? []).length >=5) {
    //do whatever you want here if guild already exist and Counters is full
    return;
} else {
    await counterChannels.updateOne(
    { Guild: guild.id },
    {
        $push: {
        Counters: {
            Names: givenName, // givenName Declaration not included.
            Types: counterType, // counterType Declaration not included.
            Channels: createdCounter.id // createdCounter Declaration not included.
        }
        }
    },
    {upsert : True} //this option will create the doc if it doesn't exist
    );

}
```

For your last part of code, you should use `findOne()` instead of `find`. Because find will try to find all the guilds that match your query and return an array. Since your guild is unique, findOne is better.

```
async execute (member) {
   const data = await serverCounters.findOne({Guild: member.guild.id});
   if(!data) return; //do what you want if no doc match the guildid

   const dataCounterOrEmptyArray = data?.Counters??[]
   const allCounterType = dataCounterOrEmptyArray.map(doc => doc.Types);
   const allCounterChannel = dataCounterOrEmptyArray.map(doc => doc.Channels);
   const allCounterName = dataCounterOrEmptyArray.map(doc => doc.Names);
   //or iterate over each element
   for (const myCounter of dataCounterOrEmptyArray) {
     console.log({myCounter});
   }
}
```